# Is the partial trace identity $\mathrm{Tr}_2 [(A\otimes B)C]=A\cdot\mathrm{Tr}_2[(\mathbb{I}_1\otimes B)C]$ true?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, trace

Suppose we have two (finite dimensional) Hilbert spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$. Let $A$ be an operator on $H_1$, and $B$ an operator on $H_2$, and $C$ an operator on $H_1 \otimes H_2$. Is the quantity (where $\mathrm{Tr}_2[\cdot]$ is the partial trace over the Hilbert space $H_2$)
$$
\mathrm{LHS} := \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left[ ( A \otimes B ) C \right]
$$
the same as
$$
\mathrm{RHS} := A \cdot \mathrm{Tr}_2 \left[ ( \mathbb{I}_1 \otimes B ) C \right] \ ?
$$
That is to say, is it true that $\mathrm{LHS} =\mathrm{RHS}$? It seems correct, but I am having difficulty proving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this identity is correct. The key is to note that $H_1 \otimes H_2$ is spanned by simple tensors, which is to say that $C$ can be expressed in the form
$$
C = \sum_{j=1}^k P_j \otimes Q_j.
$$
With that, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Tr}_2 \left[ ( A \otimes B ) C \right]
&= 
\mathrm{Tr}_2 \left[ ( A \otimes B ) \sum_{j=1}^k P_j \otimes Q_j \right] 
\\&= 
\mathrm{Tr}_2 \left[ \sum_{j=1}^k (AP_j) \otimes (BQ_j) \right] 
\\ &= \sum_{j=1}^k \mathrm{Tr}(BQ_j)(AP_j)
\\ &= A \sum_{j=1}^k \mathrm{Tr}(BQ_j)(P_j)
\\ &= A \cdot \mathrm{Tr}_2\left[ \sum_{j=1}^k P_j \otimes BQ_j\right]
\\ &= A \cdot \mathrm{Tr}_2\left[ (I \otimes B)\sum_{j=1}^k P_j \otimes Q_j\right]
 = A \cdot \mathrm{Tr}_2\left[ (I \otimes B)C\right].
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Indeed, and, for that matter, by linearity it suffices to check the identity for single monomials. The summing over $j$ just passes through, etc.